# using lapply, invisible and cast across different dataframes to create new dataframes

Tags: r, casting, lapply, invisible

At the moment I have 16 dataframes that I wish to run the cast command over them in one hit rather than one at a time. I can successfully do this by using the lapply (see code below). However, the data gets written to a list of a list and I would rather maintain the data as separate dataframes. (this is most likely inefficient but I need to do various pieces of network analysis on the data and would like to keep them separate)

```
require(dplyr)
require(readr)
require(data.table)
library(reshape)

lapply(prolist,function(x) cast(x, mgrname ~ ticker, fun.aggregate = sum ,value = "shares"))
```

where prolist contains the name of the various dataframes that I want to apply the function to.

I have found and used the invisible code in a similar situation, which generated the separate dataframes but this time I can not get it to work. My code is: Noting the cast function comes from the reshape package.

```
invisible(lapply(prolist,function(x) cast(x, mgrname ~ ticker, fun.aggregate = sum ,value = "shares")
      { assign(paste0("summary", x), x, pos=.GlobalEnv) }))
```

The error is:

```
Error: unexpected '{' in:
```

"invisible(lapply(prolist,function(x) cast(x, mgrname ~ ticker, fun.aggregate = sum ,value = "shares")
          {"

The file format goes like, with there being a file for each quarter of the year.

```
| mgrname | ticker | share |
|---------|--------|-------|
| Man A   | AAPL   |     20|
| Man A   | MSFT   |     30|
| Man A   | TLSA   |     40|
| Man B   | AAPL   |     20|
| Man B   | MSFT   |     10|
| Man B   | TLSA   |     50|
| Man C   | AAPL   |     20|
| Man C   | MSFT   |     20|
| Man C   | TLSA   |     80|
```

Any help would as always would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What package is `cast`? If not base, please include all `library` lines. Also, what format does the *list of lists*. You may be able to bind list elements into dataframe. Please illustrate with data.

Comment: the cast package comes in the reshape package

Comment: Using you code @Sathish I got this error   ->   Error in assign(paste0("c", x), x, pos = .GlobalEnv) : 
  variable names are limited to 10000 bytes